# Create new rows that are conditional on earlier rows

Tags: r, random, tidyverse

I want to create `output_df`, which adds two rows to the bottom.

The new rows are:

- assigned `NA` for column `z`, and
- `percentage` is calculated such that `sum(output_df$x == "Y" & output_df$y == "A") == 1` and `sum(output_df$x == "N" & output_df$y == "B") == 1`

In the `original_df`, the percentages do not equal 1 (e.g. `sum(original_df$x == "Y" & original_df$y == "A") != 1)`, which is why I am looking to fix it.

By adding the extra rows (e.g., `output_df[5,]`), it then sums to 1 (e.g., `sum(output_df$x == "Y" & output_df$y == "A") == 1`).

```
original_df <- data.frame(x = c("Y","N","Y","N"),
                          y = c("A","B","A","B"),
                          z = c("a","b","c","d"),
                          percentage = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5)) 

output_df <- data.frame(x = c("Y","N","Y","N","Y","N"),
                        y = c("A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                        z = c("a","b","c","d",NA , NA),
                        percentage = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3))
```

For context, my intent is to use `output_df` to feed into the `sample` function, where `replace = T`.

Comment: But, according to your rules, the initial rows for `percentage` looks wrong. Do you maybe want: `output_df$percentage <- cumsum(output_df$x == "Y") / seq(nrow(output_df))` ?

Comment: The initial rows are not meant to sum to 1, which is why I am looking to fix that. @Marcinthebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

original_df %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  do(add_row(., x = .$x[1], y = .$y[1])) %>%
  mutate(across(percentage, ~ifelse(is.na(.), 1 - sum(., na.rm = T), .))) %>%
  ungroup()
  
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   x     y     z     percentage
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 N     B     b            0.2
#> 2 N     B     d            0.5
#> 3 N     B     <NA>         0.3
#> 4 Y     A     a            0.1
#> 5 Y     A     c            0.5
#> 6 Y     A     <NA>         0.4
```